# libGL error: Ubuntu 14.10 (GNU/Linux 3.16.0-31-generic x86_64)

Tags: android-virtual-device, ubuntu-14.10

I'm trying to run android emulator - AVD via Eclipse, but error occurred:

```
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visual found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Although I've looked up the existing Q&As and followed them, it doesn't work (ex. `ln -s /usr/lib/libGL.so.1 ~/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/lib/libGL.so`). 
My OS version is `Ubuntu 14.10 (GNU/Linux 3.16.0-31-generic x86_64)`.

Please help me how to resolve the error.